# PNG error messages in command line

Tags: image, error, command-line

I use image textures a lot and regularly get the following messages pop up in command line...

libpng warning: interlace handling should be turned on when using png_read_image

libpng warning: iCCP known incorrect sRGB profile

I don’t run through cmd much unless I’m troubleshooting lagging or a regular crash so I don’t know if this contributes to performance issues.

My questions:

1. What do these error messages mean?
2. Are they important enough to worry about?
3. How can I stop them from recurring?

This has happened on various versions of blender from 2.79 through to my current 2.8.3

Comment: [libpng warning: interlace handling should be turned on when using png_read_image in Python/PyGame - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12990602/libpng-warning-interlace-handling-should-be-turned-on-when-using-png-read-image), [Solved: libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile - Magento Forums](https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/libpng-warning-iCCP-known-incorrect-sRGB-profile/td-p/127379). When using Blender  in GUI, it's likely the waring is suppressed.